# Jquery, Inside funtion I have value but when I am inserting it to html it does not show

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asynchronous, crm

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td class="data">Player IP:</td>
      <td class="value" id="user_ip"></td>
    </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have following problem. I am getting Ip in console.log but, when I am inserting it in html element it's not showing. any solution

```js
function getIp(data) {
  var ip = data; //data.comments[0].metadata.system.ip_address;
  ip = ip.toString();
  console.log("ip", ip);
  console.log("before", $("#user_ip").html()) 
  $("#user_ip").html(ip);
  console.log("after", $("#user_ip").html()) // this does not contain ip
  console.log("Ip added");
  return ip;
}
console.log("returns", getIp("123"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user_ip"></div>
```

Comment: might need to see more of your relevant code, can't replicate the problem with that

Comment: How does your HTML code look? What is the value of `data`?

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet.  As you can see, it works fine.   If you're getting the "ip" console.log, then it's *probably* that you do not have an element with id `user_ip` - I've added one to the snippet, but if you don't have one then that would be the cause.  Please [edit] the snippet so that it *reproduces* the problem for us to see.

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. So what is different between this and what you actually have? My guess is your html element does not actually exist.

Comment: Note: `console.log($("#user_ip"))` (which I changed in your snippet as it's pointless) will **always returns a jquery object** - you can't use this to test your selector - instead, use `console.log($("#user_ip").length)` which should be `=== 1`